# Finding it hard to link my database with my gui. fullname not defined?

Tags: python, ms-access

Trying to link my database with my GUI for a college project. Im new to python. I'm getting a fullname not defined error at the moment.I know its probably something simple. Its due in an hour and a half so I thought id throw it on here and see what happens. Thanks in advance guys.

```
def saveUser(self):
     name = self.fullname.get()
     email = self.email.get()
     marketing = self.optin.get()
     vehicle = self.vehicle_class.get()
     account_type = self.video.get()

     new_member = customer([fullname], email, accounttype, optin, self.video.get())
     DBfile = ".\\databaseeflow.mdb"
     conn = pypyodbc.connect(r"DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ="+DBfile)
     cursor = conn.cursor()
     SQL = "INSERT INTO AccountList (ID, [fullName], email, optin, accounttype, vehicleclass) VALUES ('" 
     SQL = SQL + "Edin Gogic" + ",'"
     SQL = SQL + "edingogic@itb.ie" + "','"
     SQL = SQL + "1" + "','"
     SQL = SQL + "video" + "','"
     SQL = SQL + "car" + "');"
```

Can anyone see an obvious issue? Thanks

Comment: Try using the full path name to your database file in your ```DBfile = "..."``` line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it. single quote missing. See how the quote in the first entry is missing. It should be `'Edin Gogic'` instead of `'Edin Gogic`.

```
class db():
    def saveUser(self):
     #name = self.fullname.get()
     #email = self.email.get()
     #marketing = self.optin.get()
     #vehicle = self.vehicle_class.get()
     #account_type = self.video.get()

     #new_member = customer([fullname], email, accounttype, optin, self.video.get())
     #DBfile = ".\\databaseeflow.mdb"
     #conn = pypyodbc.connect(r"DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ="+DBfile)
     #cursor = conn.cursor()
     SQL = "INSERT INTO AccountList (ID, [fullName], email, optin, accounttype, vehicleclass) VALUES ('" 
     SQL = SQL + "Edin Gogic" + ",'"
     SQL = SQL + "edingogic@itb.ie" + "','"
     SQL = SQL + "1" + "','"
     SQL = SQL + "video" + "','"
     SQL = SQL + "car" + "');"
     print SQL

dbx=db()
dbx.saveUser()
```

Result below:

```
INSERT INTO AccountList (ID, [fullName], email, optin, accounttype, vehicleclass) VALUES ('Edin Gogic,'edingogic@itb.ie','1','video','car');
```

Modified here:

```
def saveUser(self):
     name = self.fullname.get()
     email = self.email.get()
     marketing = self.optin.get()
     vehicle = self.vehicle_class.get()
     account_type = self.video.get()

     new_member = customer([fullname], email, accounttype, optin, self.video.get())
     DBfile = ".\\databaseeflow.mdb"
     conn = pypyodbc.connect(r"DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ="+DBfile)
     cursor = conn.cursor()
     SQL = "INSERT INTO AccountList (ID, [fullName], email, optin, accounttype, vehicleclass) VALUES ('" 
     SQL = SQL + "Edin Gogic" + "','"
     SQL = SQL + "edingogic@itb.ie" + "','"
     SQL = SQL + "1" + "','"
     SQL = SQL + "video" + "','"
     SQL = SQL + "car" + "');"
```